# What words (in Black Speech) was Sauron saying when he allegedly asked Pippin of who he was?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, sauron

What phonemes (or even words in Black Speech) could one distinguish in the below video from 1:26 to 1:29, where Sauron allegedly asked Pippin of who he was?

Comment: Related (from the book): [What did Sauron mean when he “talked” to Pippin?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/89894/31394)

Comment: **INT. EDORAS, SLEEPING QUARTERS - NIGHT.** 
*PIPPIN suddenly starts to HYPERVENTILATE . . . He STAGGERS BACKWARDS, PALANTIR held rigidly before him . . .THE GREAT EYE OF SAURON seems to LEAP from the FIRE . . . PIPPIN is bathed in the FIERY RED LIGHT.*

*PIPPIN sinks to his KNEES, his mouth open in a soundless SCREAM ... He FALLS BACKWARDS, powerless to release the FIERY GLOBE.*

**MERRY:** *Help! Someone help him!*

*GANDALF wakes with a start! Just as ARAGORN enters, and
wrenches the PALANTIR from PIPPIN'S HANDS . . . PIPPIN FALLS to
the FLOOR!* - Nothing in the script of use.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it could be *ash nazg thrakatum*, which (being similar the third line of the Ring inscription) is perhaps intended to mean something like "Bring me the One Ring".

Comment: I never said my translation was a literal translation, and it's standard practice to include articles in the target language as appropriate if the source language lacks articles. I only included "One" because Sauron would certainly have that particular ring in mind.